# ERROR: All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Gradle выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension

Что надо сделать? Я всего лишь обновился до версии 3.3.1.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавить в build.gradle такую строку:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
```

в итоге будет как-то так:

```
android { 
    ...
    flavorDimensions "default"
    ...
}
```

вот [документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#flavor_dimensions) по этому вопросу.